# Cocoapod not importing properly

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

I have some proprietary code I'm not able to share. But I need to import the code into another project. We typically use cocoapods for this sort of things but this project is behaving differently, and I can't figure out why. In the first project, let's call it `FooKit`, there are a number of dependencies which have been imported as pods, lets call them `BarKit`, `BazKit`, and `ZotKit`. I ran the `create podspec` command and built it all out correctly (I think), linting the podspec isn't throwing anything unexpected.

To test this out, I create a new project, which is just an empty project. I did the whole `pod init`. I setup the podfile and ran `pod install`, and it ran successfully. In the workspace, I now have the `App` and `Pods` projects. If I tap on the `Pods` project, I can see the list of targets. All of the dependencies of the `FooKit` have been installed, and they are all yellow toolbox icons. `FooKit` is also in the list of targets, but its icon is a red bullseye.

In the `App` project, if I go into the view controller and do

```
import Foundation
import FooKit

class viewController: UIViewController {
    // View Controller boiler plate code
}
```

I get the error `No such module 'FooKit'`. But I can import any of the dependencies of `FooKit`, like this

```
import Foundation
import BarKit
import BazKit
import ZotKit

// View controller code from above
```

That doesn't throw any errors. What am I doing wrong? I need to access the functions built out in `FooKit`.

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being that in the new podspec I had made, I hadn't specified some of the other dependencies for `BazKit`. This made it so that certain .swift files in both the new project I had made and the `FooKit` project were showing different versions. When I had specified in the podspec for `FooKit` all the correct dependencies versions, then everything resolved itself.